# Display custom error in error.aspx page in asp.net webforms

Tags: asp.net, web-config, custom-errors

I want to show the Custom Errors in error.aspx page when any error occur. Its redirecting to error.aspx when error happens. But not showing the message.

I set web.config like

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="/error.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/notfound.aspx" /></customErrors>
```

Is there any way to show the error message in error.aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [GetLastError()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpserverutility.getlasterror) and show the error.

```
// Get the last error from the server
var ex = Server.GetLastError();

if (null != ex)
{
   // get and render here the error, there are a lot more info to see.
   txtLiteral.Text = ex.Message;
}

// and clear the error from the server
Server.ClearError();
```

But I suggest to write it down to a log, and not show it to your users. Also locally there is not reason for custom page, leave it as they are to see the errors.

Comment: Ok. But where i should write this code, in error.aspx??

Comment: @Vahid in `notfound.aspx` that you ask for